# What is the best way to integrate a small angular.js application into Wordpress?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working on adding a small one-page AngularJS application to my friend's Wordpress site. The application will take some user input and generate on-screen output using that input. It will also log the user input for analysis purposes.

I will need to be able to host the files for that page on my friend's site as well as create a back-end script that can capture the user input and store it to a MySQL database.

I have worked with WordPress sites before but have never customized them or written a plugin. How would you go about making this happen?

I will select the answer that leads me down the most efficient / effective path. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around for a while, I ran across the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Using this helped me add custom JavaScript to the specific page that needed Angular support.

Here is information on how to use ACF to add JavaScript support:
https://www.godaddy.com/garage/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/

Here is the plugin itself:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/